# wrapping UiApp functions in a Library

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using sort of wrapping functions to add widgets to UiApp, like the sample below

```
function newButton(text, handler, callBack) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  return app.createButton(text).addClickHandler(app.createServerClickHandler(handler).addCallbackElement(callBack));
}
```

- it works fine when used within the same script like below

  panel.add(newButton("Submit", "myHandler", panel));
- but when including newButton function within a Library (ex. myLib) and it's called as myLib.newButton, I would get an error: 
  "Error encountered: Unknown macro myLib.myHandler"

  panel.add(myLib.newButton("Submit", "myHandler", panel));

Any way of avoiding this problem, while keeping myHandler in the current script (not in myLib)?
Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.
In your current script (wherein you imported the reference to the library) 
create;

```
function myLib.myHandler(){
}
```

As your handler (string) keep passing the name 'myHandler'. The above function will be called by the button created in your library script.

It seems like apps script is using this namespace structure to avoid name collision.

You should keep in mind that this could purposely be not-documented by google for a reason. Maybe this current structure could be changed in the future. Or maybe im just being paranoid ;-)

Comment: thanks for such a good idea, however when saving the script I am getting the following error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Comment: My bad. Try

myLib.myHandler = function(e){
}

Is essentialy the same but another way to write the function.

Comment: Awesome, it's working now, I knew it was trivial, but the trivial is usually the hardest || Thanks a lot for your valuable support !!